# VS 2017 doesn't build C# forms project

Tags: c#, compilation, visual-studio-2017

I Created a C# forms program and tried build it for the 1st time.
it says build failed and there is no error or warning , but in the building output windows it says Project 'X' is not up to date. Missing output file.
notice that there is no file beacuse this is the first time I compile the project I tried deleting the bin , obj and .vs folder but it did not work

```
1>Project 'Bits RW' is not up to date. Missing output file 'C:\Users\shady\source\repos\Bits RW\Bits RW\bin\Debug\BitsRW.exe'.
1>------ Build started: Project: Bits RW, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: you need to run VS with elevated privileges.

Comment: do you mean run as adminstrator ? if you mean that I tried it. but it used to compile other projects when I run normaily

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/10/07/did-you-know-you-can-configure-the-msbuild-verbosity-in-the-output-window-329/ Ask VS to print more info for you.

Comment: It's already set to diagnostic and it doesn't print anything else

Comment: 1>Project 'Bits RW' is not up to date. Missing output file 'C:\Users\shady\source\repos\Bits RW\Bits RW\bin\Debug\BitsRW.exe'.
1>------ Build started: Project: Bits RW, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Post the whole build spew in your question as code so that we can read it.  Does your solution have a single project or multiple projects.  Are you building BitsRW.exe, or is something else your are building relying on it.

Comment: it has just BitsRW project wich I am trying to build. I didn't wrote single line of code in my project I just designed the UI and wanted to see while running before going to programing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot guys I solved the problem by reseting visual studio using visual studio installer. it downloaded some file the rebooted the computer and it works fine